# PATCH request in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, patch, azure-data-factory

I want to scale an elastic pool in Azure Data Factory before my pipeline runs. However, for scaling an elastic pool or azure data warehouse I have to perform a PATCH request. This is the first time I heard of a PATCH method and after browsing the glorious web I haven't found any useful information other than creating an Azure Logic app or Azure Functions app.

I want to limit the orchestration to Azure Data Factory: the documentation can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/elasticpools/update

Comment: Please vote: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/34475443-support-patch-method-in-web-activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, Azure Data Factory doesn’t support PATCH request.

I would suggest you to vote up an idea submitted by another Azure customer.

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/34475443-support-patch-method-in-web-activity

All of the feedback you share in these forums will be monitored and reviewed by the Microsoft engineering teams responsible for building Azure.